# How to temporarily disable a comment delimiter when using listings

Tags: listings

In the preamble of my document, I put the following command to allow strings wrapped with `<` and `>` printed as italic-styled comment:

```
\lstset{morecomment=[s]{<}{>},commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape}
```

And according to my understanding of the documentation of `listings` package, if I want to temporarily disable this delimiter, I should use `deletecomment=[s]{<}{>}` as optional argument of a particular `lstlisting` environment:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[deletecomment=[s]{<}{>}]
\lstset{morecomment=[s]{<}{>},commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape}
\end{lstlisting}
```

But LaTeX issued an error because of this.

So what is the correct way to disable a comment delimiter?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{morecomment=[s]{<}{>},commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[deletecomment=[s]{<}{>}]
<text>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the parsing of the `lstlisting` environment's optional argument. When the `]` character in

```
deletecomment=[s]{<}{>}
```

is found, LaTeX assumes that it marks the end of that optional argument. This problem and a solution to it are explained in subsection 2.3 of the `listings` documentation.

> `language=[77]Fortran` does not work inside an optional argument. You must put braces around the value if a value with optional argument is used inside an optional argument. In the case here write `language={[77]Fortran}` to select Fortran 77.

If you apply that trick here, by writing

```
deletecomment={[s]{<}{>}}
```

instead, everything works as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{morecomment=[s]{<}{>},commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<text>
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[deletecomment={[s]{<}{>}}]
<text>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for explanation. Your answer clarified obscurity in my mind that I was not aware of. :-)